# SSAS Cube not showing data when browsing the measures

Tags: ssas-2008

I am using SSAS2008.

I'm new to SSAS cubes , and I've have a problem with a SSAS cube, with it not showing data in measures when I'm browsing it. I have noticed that the issue is present for all the SSAS cubes in the database.

What I have tried:
I did a full process of the cube, it finished processing successfully. ( it finished the processing in a rather short time 10-15 seconds ). My colleagues told me that it should have been close to 2 min. - probably the issue is here.
I did check the CALCULATIONS tab, it has only CALCULATE.
I can see data in my DSV when I explore the tables used for the measure.
I have checked the JOINs in the dimension usage.
I checked the partition for my measure group and I have noticed the estimated rows and size is 0.

Can someone please advice what else am I missing ?

Thanks,Bogdan

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the problem was with some data in my tables.

I was able to figure out the issues by using the Error Configuration : Report and continue for KeyNotFound and NullKeyConvertedToUnknown.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPOxc.jpg)